# Xamarin for Visual Studio Intellisense doesn't show any class besides the one it is in and system ones

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, syntax-highlighting, intellisense

I got back into my project after a week of not touching it, and intellisense suddenly just isn't showing stuff, and also highlighting is gone. This happens for any class that is imported or created by me, for example:

`using Android.App;` <- Doesn't get highlighted
`using System.Linq;` <- No highlighting
`Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar t;` <- Not highlighted
`string s;` <- Gets highlighted
`EventArgs e;` <- Also highlighted

Intellisense isn't showing anything besides system classes, and also imported system classes like linq, but isn't showing anything from imported android stuff, or classes written by me, except for the current class:
File1.cs:

```
class Example1 {
    //Intellisense suggests Example1 here
    //But it doesn't suggest Example2
}
```

---

File2.cs:

```
class Example2 {
    //Intellisense suggests Example2 here
    //But it doesn't suggest Example1
}
```

I tried restarting VS and my computer, cleaning and rebuilding (the project compiles), and also resetting my import/export settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the project. > Close solution. > Reopen solution. This fixed this for me.

Comment: Rebuild crashed, restarted VS and it fixed itself. Weird, I restarted it before a couple times.